# how to show that differential of a representation is a Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Fix an integer $n\geq 0$,  let $V_n$ be the complex vector space of polynomials in two complex variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ homogeneous of degree n. Define a representation 
$$\phi_n:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(V_n)$$by
\begin{equation}\label{e5}
\phi_n(A)P\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    z_1  \\
    z_2 
  \end{bmatrix}\right)=P\left(A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
    z_1  \\
    z_2 
  \end{bmatrix}\right)
  \end{equation}
Now consider the differential $d\phi_n$ of the representation $\phi_n$. Then  $d\phi_n:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\to\mathfrak{gl}(V_n)$ is defined by $$d\phi_n(\gamma'(0))=\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_n\circ\gamma)(t)\bigg|_{t=0}$$ where $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth curve on $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with $\gamma(0)=Id:=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$.

**Question:**  Show that $d\phi_n$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism

**Attempt**: Let $\alpha,\beta$ be any two differentiable curves on $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)=Id$

1. Well-definedness:

If $\alpha'(0)=\beta'(0)$ then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_n\circ\alpha)(t)\bigg|_{t=0}  =\phi_n'(\alpha(t)).\alpha'(t)\big|_{t=0}=\phi_n'(\alpha(0)).\alpha'(0)=\phi_n'(\beta(0)).\beta'(0)=\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_n\circ\beta)(t)\bigg|_{t=0}
\end{align*}.

2. We show that $d\phi_n$ preserves the addition: \begin{equation}d\phi_n(\alpha'(0)+\beta'(0))=d\phi_n((\alpha+\beta)'(0))=\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_n\circ (\alpha+\beta))(t)\bigg|_{t=0}=\phi_n'((\alpha+\beta)(0)).(\alpha+\beta)'(0)\end{equation} 
   On the other hand 
   $$d\phi_n(\alpha'(0))+d\phi_n(\beta'(0))=\frac{d}{dt}\Big((\phi_n\circ \alpha)(t)+(\phi_n\circ \beta(t)\Big)\bigg|_{t=0}=\phi_n'(Id)\big(\alpha'(0)+\beta'(0)\big)$$

But I couldn't show that $$\phi_n'(2.Id)=\phi_n'(Id)$$

I think there must be something wrong here. But where?

3. We show $d\phi_n([\alpha'(0),\beta'(0)])=[d\phi_n(\alpha'(0)),d\phi_n(\beta'(0)]$

\begin{align*}
d\phi_n([\alpha'(0),\beta'(0)]) &=d\phi_n\big(\alpha'(0)\beta'(0)-\beta'(0)\alpha'(0)\big)=d\phi_n\big(\alpha'(0)\beta'(0)\big)-d\phi_n\big(\beta'(0)\alpha'(0)\big)
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
[d\phi_n(\alpha'(0)),d\phi_n(\beta'(0)]&=d\phi_n(\alpha'(0))d\phi_n(\beta'(0))-d\phi_n(\beta'(0))d\phi_n(\alpha'(0)) \\ &=\frac{d}{dt}\phi_n(\alpha(t)\beta(t))\bigg|_{t=0}-\frac{d}{dt}\phi_n(\beta(t)\alpha)(t)\bigg|_{t=0}
\end{align*}

But I couldn't show the equality $$d\phi_n\big(\alpha'(0)\beta'(0)\big)=\frac{d}{dt}\phi_n(\alpha(t)\beta(t))\bigg|_{t=0}$$

Comment: In general, the differential of *any* homomorphism of Lie groups is a homomorphism of their Lie algebras. A proof is in any book on Lie groups (e.g. *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups* by Hilgert and Neeb).